# Is local Shiny development secure?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to developing Shiny apps, so this might be a silly question. I'm working on an app that's in a folder on my desktop (that is, all local), and I run the app locally through the "Run App" function in RStudio.

Is this a secure way of doing this? I assume this is how most Shiny development works, but I can't find anything explicit online saying this is a secure method.

I appreciate any help here. Thanks!

Comment: What does secure mean to you? You can be completely disconnected from any networks and still develop Shiny apps. You can create destructive Shiny apps also, so... what are you wanting to be secure against?

Comment: Good point... Let me clarify. If you were developing a Shiny app with sensitive data and running it through a folder on your desktop (but never deploying it to the web) would you have security concerns about the data being accessible to third parties? I assume the answer is "no" since the development is local, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: However has access to your folder via file-system will have access to the data and the app contents